# NVD3: labels for second y-axis in MultiChart?

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

Is it possible to specify a label for the second y-axis in an NVD3 (1.8.3+) MultiChart? The following correctly sets a label on the left-hand side of the graph, but not the right:

```
chart.yAxis1.axisLabel('Liters');

chart.yAxis2.axisLabel('Gallons');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, turned out that the right side was being cut off.  I solved it by including a margin when I defined the multichart model.

```
  `var chart = nv.models.multiChart()
      .margin({top: 30, right: 90, bottom: 50, left: 70})
      .color(d3.scale.category10().range());
```

That fixed the problem for me, might be worth checking it out.  The multichart example on [github](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/examples/multiChart.html) also has a .margin setting in their code.